# Error 400 when using form to call POST API from sveltekit to goiang backend

Tags: go, post, sveltekit

i am new with sveltekit and programming in general.

for my code here, I try to send 'name' and 'deposit' value to the db using golang as backend API.

this is my code in frontend:

```html
<!-- /src/routes/account/+page.svelte -->
<script>
    export let form
</script>

<h1>Create your account here</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <p>{ form?.message || ""}</p>
    <!-- <p>{ message }</p> -->
    <label>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value={form?.name ?? ""}>
    </label>
    <label>
        Deposit
        <input type="number" step=0.01 name="deposit" id="">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Create User</button>
</form>
```

```js
// /src/routes/account/+page.server.js
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request, fetch, cookies }) => {
        const data = await request.formData()
        const name = data.get("name")
        const deposit = data.get("deposit")
        for (let [key, value] of data) {
            console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        }
        

        const body = JSON.stringify({ name, deposit})
        console.log("body:", body);
        const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/account", {
            body,
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            mode: "no-cors"
        })
        if (!name || !deposit) {
            return fail(400, {
                name,
                message: "Missing name or deposit"
            })
        }
        cookies.set('name', name, {path: '/'})
        console.log(`response status: ${res.status}, cookies: ${cookies.get("name")}`);
        return {message: 'account created'}
    }
}
```

when i submit the form, it return error 400: bad request. And the error message is this: "invalid character 'a' in literal null (expecting 'u')".

I try to search about the error, and i think maybe it did not pass correct JSON object to the backend.

is there anything wrong with my code? thanks in advance for the help